# Use in code HTML for GET in ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, get

I am trying to figure out a way to just use my inline HTML as the URL for the ajax GET method instead of getting the data from a separate webpage. Is this possible?

This is my ajax code:

```
       $.ajax({
          type: "GET",
          url: $(elm).attr("href"),
          success: function(data){
            $("#pageslide-content").html(data)
              .queue(function(){
                $(this).dequeue();

                // restore working order to all anchors
                $("#pageslide-slide-wrap a").unbind('click').click(function(elm){
                  document.location.href = elm.target.href;
                });

                // add hook for a close button
                $(this).find('.pageslide-close').unbind('click').click(function(elm){
                  _closeSlide(elm);
                  $(this).find('pageslide-close').unbind('click');
                });
                settings.complete();
              });
          }
        });
      });
```

Any help would be great!

**UPDATE**

```
SOLVED:

             $("#pageslide-content").html('<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /><title></title></head?<body><strong style="color:#C63; font-size:28px; font-weight:bold;">TEST</strong></body></html>')
              .queue(function(){
                $(this).dequeue();

                // restore working order to all anchors
                $("#pageslide-slide-wrap a").unbind('click').click(function(elm){
                  document.location.href = elm.target.href;
                });

                // add hook for a close button
                $(this).find('.pageslide-close').unbind('click').click(function(elm){
                  _closeSlide(elm);
                  $(this).find('pageslide-close').unbind('click');
                });
                settings.complete();
              });
```

Comment: Have you tried it? It should work as long as `$(elm).attr("href")` evaluates to a proper URL string.

Comment: for that, no need to make an ajax call, just JQuery selectors are enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
             $("#pageslide-content").html('<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /><title></title></head?<body><strong style="color:#C63; font-size:28px; font-weight:bold;">TEST</strong></body></html>')
              .queue(function(){
                $(this).dequeue();

                // restore working order to all anchors
                $("#pageslide-slide-wrap a").unbind('click').click(function(elm){
                  document.location.href = elm.target.href;
                });

                // add hook for a close button
                $(this).find('.pageslide-close').unbind('click').click(function(elm){
                  _closeSlide(elm);
                  $(this).find('pageslide-close').unbind('click');
                });
                settings.complete();
              });
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, of course it is possible.  You can get a string from anywhere you want, and use it for your URL property.

Comment: I updated my OP with the HTML code in place of the page. However, it does not show anything?